# how to apply generic json-patch operation via neo4j or apoc

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, json-patch

Is there a fancy or tricky way to apply an arbitrary array of [jsonpatch](http://jsonpatch.com)-like to maps with cypher or even apoc?

So if i have

- a map `{a: 0, b: 0, c: 0}`
- a collection of operations encoded in maps, say `[{replace: "a", value: 1}, {replace: "b", value: 1}]`. I know it's not rellay jsonpatch but it's all I need. If there is a fully fledged jsonpatch solution, even better.

I seek a procedure, a concatenation of procedures or a neat way in cypher that produces `{a: 1, b: 1, c: 0}`

There is `apoc.map.setKey(map, key, value)` found in https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_map_functions but that only manipulates one value at once. I tried combining that with cypher's `FOREACH` but **I need to indeed mutate a map and not a node.**

my try was

```
create (:TEST {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0});

match (t:TEST)
with t, [{replace: "a", value: 1}, {replace: "b", value: 1}] as refs
foreach(ref in refs
    | set t = apoc.map.setKey(properties(t), ref.replace, 
ref.value))
return *;
```

Of course I could always let the client do the jsonpatch operations, but I prefer a way to do it within the tx. I know I could also write a procedure myself as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this...

```
MATCH (test:TEST {a:0, b:0, c:0})
SET test += {a: 1, b: 1}
RETURN test
```

Comment: thank you, I think that's much more concise than what I had. But still, I don't want to mutate a node, I just want to mutate a collection.

Comment: sorry about that... i got stuck on "I seek a procedure, a concatenation of procedures or a neat way in cypher that produces {a: 1, b: 1, c: 0}"